# PowerShell - Count OS Versions in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I am looking to count the number of OS versions in AD. I have this working, but not entirely satisfied with the output. The issue is the OperatingSystem and OperatingSystemVersion are merged into the same column. Ideally, I want to have three headers: Name, Version, Count.

What I get is:

```
Name                                          Count
----                                          -----
Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0 (19044)              26
Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0 (18362)               1
Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0 (19045)               8
Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0 (18363)              11
Windows 10 Enterprise, 10.0 (19042)               1
Windows 8.1 Enterprise, 6.3 (9600)                2
```

This is what I am using:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Server XXX -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemVersion -SearchBase 'OU=XXX,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx'
        
$Results = ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){
    [PSCustomObject] @{     
        OperatingSystem = $Computer.OperatingSystem
        Version = $Computer.OperatingSystemVersion
    }
}

$Results | Group-Object -Property OperatingSystem, Version | Select-Object Name, Count
```

And a slightly more condensed version:

```
Get-ADComputer -Server SHR -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase 'OU=XXX,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx' |
Group-Object -Property OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion |
Select-Object Name,Count | Sort-Object Name
```

I would like to get something like:

Name Version Count

Comment: **Never** post a screenshot of text here if you can avoid it. But as for the question: how do you want to break out the version? Do you want the 10.0 or just the 19044? And do you want to pull out parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the values from the first element in each group:

```
$Groups = $Results | Group-Object -Property OperatingSystem, Version |Sort Name
$Groups |Select-Object @{Name='OperatingSystem';Expression={$_.Group[0].OperatingSystem}},@{Name='Version';Expression={$_.Group[0].Version}}, Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Different way to do it, grouping by `OperatingSystemVersion` since those should already be unique due to the OS build:

```bash
$getADComputerSplat = @{
    Server     = 'SHR'
    Filter     = '*'
    Properties = 'OperatingSystem', 'OperatingSystemVersion'
    SearchBase = 'OU=XXX,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx'
}

Get-ADComputer @getADComputerSplat |
    Group-Object -Property OperatingSystemVersion |
    Select-Object @(
        @{ N = 'Name'; E = { $_.Group[0].OperatingSystem }}
        @{ N = 'Version'; E = 'Name' }
        'Count') |
    Sort-Object Name
```